# Rails 4: Undefined method in form, one-to-one association project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm building an app which consists on sharing résumés. I am using Devise gem. Each user is able to create `only one` résumé. I made the models and and their relations.  `Resume belongs_to User` and `User has_one Resume`.

After making the views, I wanted to test my app but I got the error  coming from the _form.html.erb: `undefined method resumes_path' for #<#<Class:0x00...>`.

Here is my **form.rb**:

```
<%= simple_form_for @resume, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% if @resume.errors.any? %>
    <div id="errors">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@resume.errors.count, "error") %>
        prevented this resume from saving
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @resume.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li>
            <%= msg %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } %>
  </div>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

In order to give more details about my code, I made this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rrubmo/6dd9f83d07c4938f6642). If you need me to provide more details, please precise them.

In this application I just want the user to be able to create only one Resume and then he will be able to share it. So the expected behaviour of the form is to create a Resume with two elements: `title` and `description`, this is my first time doing one-to-one modeling, and i don't know how it should be organised.

Comment: Look like something is missing in config/routes.rb. What is the output of `rake routes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` try using a plural name in resources:

```
  resources :resumes, except: [:index]
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Answer (score 0):

After submitting your form, application is redirecting you to resumes_path (which is **index**-action for resumes by default). Problem is that it's the only thing you are not allowing in your routes file by using `except:` like this:

```
resources :resume, except: [:index]
```

Also, as mentioned before, `:resume` should be written in **plural**.